# getElementById and innerText only changes one, not all

Tags: getelementbyid

I have searched up and down for days, no luck.  Please help.  This projec will only be used in IE7, it has a text box that you enter your name, and onclick should populate that name into all the spans.  this is where I am at, but it only changes the first span.

Please Help.  Thank you.

```
<form>
<input id="i" value="My_Name">

<input type="button" value="Enter" 

onClick="document.getElementById('initials').innerText= i.value;">
</form>


<span id="initials">name</span>
<br />
<span id="initials">name</span>
<br />
<span id="initials">name</span>
<br />
<span id="initials">name</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

An element's `id` should be unique in the document. You cannot use the same `id` for multiple elements. Some options:

- Give the elements different IDs and retrieve them independently using multiple invocations of `getElementById`
- Retrieve the elements by tag name using `getElementsByTagName` and loop over the results. (Consider wrapping the common `span` elements in a `div` and selecting by tag name relative to that wrapper.)
- Give the elements a common class name and use some implementation of `getElementsByClassName` to retrieve the results
- Give the elements a common value for the `name` attribute (which does not need to be unique) and use `getElementsByName`.

Comment: first off thank you for the fast answer.  I knew that the ID could be causing a problem and though about using classes instead.  Unfortuantely I am only able to use the first example.  I do not want to go this route since it will be very cumbersome when I start to get more and more (intials1, initials2, initials3...).

i do not think that the others are working in IE7, getElementsByTagName, getElementsByClassName, getElementsByName.

Please help.  Thank you.

Comment: hope to get some clarification.  I am so close to finishing this.  i am not sure why it isn't working, unless some of the javascript tags arn't working in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is that `id` should be different where you are using same `initials` id for all span elements. You can give them different ids and try like this:

```
document.getElementById('initials1').innerText= i.value;
document.getElementById('initials2').innerText= i.value;
document.getElementById('initials3').innerText= i.value;
document.getElementById('initials4').innerText= i.value;
```

---

So you can modify your html like this:

```
<span id="initials1">name</span>
<br />
<span id="initials2">name</span>
<br />
<span id="initials3">name</span>
<br />
<span id="initials4">name</span>
```

And

```
<form>
  <input id="i" value="My_Name">
  <input type="button" value="Enter" onClick="doIt();">
</form>
```

JS:

```
function doIt(){
  document.getElementById('initials1').innerText= i.value;
  document.getElementById('initials2').innerText= i.value;
  document.getElementById('initials3').innerText= i.value;
  document.getElementById('initials4').innerText= i.value;
}
```

---

If you don't want to use ids, you can use `getElementsByTagName` and change function like this:

```
function doIt(){
  var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
  for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++){
     spans[i].innerText = document.getElementById('i').value;
  }
}
```

Comment: man I am so close.  I tried doing it without the duplicate IDs.  Your method of the redone form and the last doIt function do not seem to work.  I have...

Comment: <!-- function doIt(){ var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span'); for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++){ spans[i].innerText = document.getElementById('i').value; } } --> <form> <input id="i" value="My_Name"> <input type="button" value="Enter" onClick="doIt();"> </form> <span id="initials">name</span> <br /> <span id="initials">name</span> <br /> <span id="initials">name</span> <br /> <span id="initials">name</span>

Comment: hope to get some clarification.  I am so close to finishing this.  i am not sure why it isn't working, unless some of the javascript tags arn't working in IE7.